# Lock-Free Data Structures in C++ Compare and Swap Routine

Tags: c++, lock-free, atomic

In this paper: [Lock-Free Data Structures](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:yDuTpGAIlygJ:erdani.com/publications/cuj-2004-10.pdf+lock+free+c%2B%2B&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjNodk4nEL66U4qu4oZGis4GdGY3VxHk5M35_5DEdSK3bbTN8XK25dnsmO20tBfcVG_Ul1PxtNPJy2hRznZWMKW-OfQGA6cGjavEhOOoewQpVCoWvu8teuIOQZxBVA5zM60dpwK&sig=AHIEtbTqSFtplVhgj-CAIouJTDast-D20g) ([pdf](http://erdani.com/publications/cuj-2004-10.pdf)) the following "Compare and Swap" fundamental is shown:

```
template <class T>
bool CAS(T* addr, T exp, T val)
{
  if (*addr == exp)
  {
    *addr = val;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then says

> The entire procedure is atomic

But how is that so?  Is it not possible that some other actor could change the value of `addr` between the `if` and the assignment?  In which case, assuming all code is using this CAS fundamental, it would be found the next time something "expected" it to be a certain way, and it wasn't.  However, that doesn't change the fact that it could happen, in which case, is it still atomic?  What about the other actor returning true, even when it's changes were overwritten by this actor?  If that can't possibly happen, then why?

I want to believe the author, so what am I missing here?  I am thinking it must be obvious.   My apologies in advance if this seems trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He is describing an atomic operation which is given by the implementation, "somehow." That is pseudo-code for something implemented in hardware.

Comment: Yes, the author is asserting that the operation is atomic, then giving you some code so you understand what it does.  One implementation (that is atomic) is Microsoft's InterlockedCompareExchange() (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683560(VS.85).aspx).  If you just compile that code, it is most certainly not atomic.

Comment: With GCC, you have similarily atomic operators including CAS described here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html